# Bokeh plot disappearing when panning or zooming

Tags: python, bokeh

This simple Bokeh plot disappears when I try to pan or zoom with my mouse/mousewheel. The plotted line vanishes until I let go of my mouse, at which point it returns. How to fix?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.driving import linear
from bokeh.models.tools import PanTool, WheelZoomTool

p = figure(sizing_mode="stretch_both", y_axis_location="right", x_axis_type="datetime")
pan_tool = p.select(dict(type=PanTool))
pan_tool.dimensions="width"
zoom_tool = p.select(dict(type=WheelZoomTool))
zoom_tool.dimensions="width"
p.x_range.follow = "end"
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.01
p.xaxis.ticker.desired_num_ticks = 8
r1 = p.step(range(3000), range(3000), color="red", line_width=0.4)
curdoc().add_root(p)
```

To run it:

```
bokeh serve --show bokeh_test.py
```

Comment: @mosc9575 What does putting "scale_both" achieve? I tried doing that and nothing got fixed.

Comment: When I run this it looks like the standard (expected) Level-of-Detail downsampling for interactive performance. That said, LOD functions best with "scatter" type glyphs rather than "line" type glyphs. You can disable LOD downsampling by setting `lod_threshold=None`